# Default Windows 10 c:\users\<user> security settings?

Tags: windows-10, permissions

On my C:\Users\MYNAME, on Properties > Security > Advanced:

- MYUSER ; Full Control ; Inherited from None
- Everyone ; Read & Execute ; Inherited from C:\Users
- Administrators ; Full Control ; Inherited from C:\Users
- SYSTEM ; Full Control ; Inherited from C:\Users
- Users ; Read & Execute ; Inherited from C:\Users
- The Disable Inheritance button is enabled

Now, on my C:\Windows.old\Users\MYNAME, on Properties > Security >Advanced:

- MYUSER ; Full Control ; Inherited from None
- Administrators ; Full Control ; Inherited from C:\Users
- SYSTEM ; Full Control ; Inherited from C:\Users
- The Enable Inheritance button is enabled

Which one is correct?  Just seems strange that they differ, and I don't have a 2nd machine to check.

Comment: How exactly do they differ?

Comment: That's answered in the OP.  Unless I am missing something...

Comment: I am looking at each list.  I don't see any difference between the items that  exist in both lists.  The reason the second list is missing items is because its a system generated folder that has no use for the other items and the other list is a system generated folders that do require them.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new user.  Check its security settings.